# Error (android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException) while downloading images from the server showing in ListView using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-networking, android-webservice

I am facing some problem while downloading images from the server and showing in the ListView using AsyncTask in Android.

It showing me error that downloading the images are in the Main (UI) Thread But I am using the AsyncTask for that purpose.

Here is my MainActivity.java code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String[] imageURLArray = new String[]{
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7315/9046944633_881f24c4fa_s.jpg",
            "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3777/9049174610_bf51be8a07_s.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7324/9046946887_d96a28376c_s.jpg",
            "http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2828/9046946983_923887b17d_s.jpg",
            "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3810/9046947167_3a51fffa0b_s.jpg",
            "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3773/9049175264_b0ea30fa75_s.jpg",
            "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3781/9046945893_f27db35c7e_s.jpg",
            "http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5344/9049177018_4621cb63db_s.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7307/9046947621_67e0394f7b_s.jpg",
            "http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5457/9046948185_3be564ac10_s.jpg",
            "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3752/9046946459_a41fbfe614_s.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7403/9046946715_85f13b91e5_s.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7315/9046944633_881f24c4fa_s.jpg",
            "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3777/9049174610_bf51be8a07_s.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7324/9046946887_d96a28376c_s.jpg",
            "http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2828/9046946983_923887b17d_s.jpg",
            "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3810/9046947167_3a51fffa0b_s.jpg",
            "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3773/9049175264_b0ea30fa75_s.jpg",
            "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3781/9046945893_f27db35c7e_s.jpg",
            "http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5344/9049177018_4621cb63db_s.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7307/9046947621_67e0394f7b_s.jpg",
            "http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5457/9046948185_3be564ac10_s.jpg",
            "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3752/9046946459_a41fbfe614_s.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7403/9046946715_85f13b91e5_s.jpg"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, R.layout.imageitem, imageURLArray);
        listView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    }
}
```

Here is my ImageAdapter.java code.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private String[] imageURLArray;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                        String[] imageArray) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, imageArray);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        imageURLArray = imageArray;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imageitem, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.testImage);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = null;
        try {
            URL imageURL = new URL(imageURLArray[position]);
            imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageURL.openStream());
            viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("error", "Downloading Image Failed");
            viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        String imageURL;
        ImageView imageView;
    }

    private class DownloadAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, ViewHolder> {
        @Override
        protected ViewHolder doInBackground(ViewHolder... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //load image directly
            ViewHolder viewHolder = params[0];
            try {
                URL imageURL = new URL(viewHolder.imageURL);
                viewHolder.bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageURL.openStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("error", "Downloading Image Failed");
                viewHolder.bitmap = null;
            }

            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ViewHolder result) {
            if (result.bitmap == null) {
                result.imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            } else {
                result.imageView.setImageBitmap(result.bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the link that have the full project.

http://www.mediafire.com/download/70pxv6ib584x9j7/DownloadImagesInListView.rar

Here is the error stack that is showing.

```
09-29 18:33:37.859    5550-5550/com.example.android.downloadimagesinlistview E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.downloadimagesinlistview, PID: 5550
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at 

    android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1161)
                at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
                at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
                at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
                at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:199)
                at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:470)
                at com.example.android.downloadimagesinlistview.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.java:48)
                at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
                at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
                at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
                at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
                at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
                at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2151)
                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
                at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2116)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1873)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1084)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5990)
                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(
```

Comment: Do you expect us to download the project? Please, post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: sigh. Just past the code of your code with async. People shoulnt be forced to download shady .rars

Comment: Your `ImageAdapter` (presumably some form of `ListAdapter`), in its `getView()` method, is passing a URL into something (perhaps an `ImageView`) that is attempting to download the whatever-it-is.

Comment: This error is pretty standard ! please try to your analysis also and code where you feel there may be problem

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I have added my Activities code.

Comment: You're never starting the AsyncTask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception occurs when you perform network related operations on the main thread. For downloading the images either you have to perform the operation in AsyncTask or Use [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library.

Using Picasso use this

```
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(imageURLArray[position]).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(viewHolder.imageView);
```

at the place of

```
Bitmap imageBitmap = null;
try {
  URL imageURL = new URL(imageURLArray[position]);
  imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageURL.openStream());
  viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO: handle exception
  Log.e("error", "Downloading Image Failed");
  viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
}
```